# How do I call ajax if user enter some text on html Input field with Jquery/Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a html user profile form where data is comming from mysql database. I'm currently calling ajax when user hover out the mouse from input field using jquery `.blur()`. Now I want to know how can I call this ajax when user **actually** type something on input field ?

**Jquery/Ajax Code:**

```
<script>
$("#given_name").blur(function(){   

var given_name =  $("#given_name").val(); 

$.ajax({
  url: 'certainfield.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  "given_name" : given_name
}).done(function ( data ) {
  $('#r').append(data);
});

});
</script>
```

**Html Code:**

```
<tr>
<td>Given name</td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $res['given_name'] ?>" name="given_name" 
id="given_name" placeholder="Given name"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: use keyup instead of blur. But you have to be more sophisticated to prevent multiple async calls that may return in an unpredictable order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("#given_name").change(...)` instead of `$("#given_name").blur(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to read user input one usually uses `onkeyup` event then reads the data that has been entered into the field.

```
$('#given_name').on('keyup', function () {
    var given_name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'certainfield.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        "given_name": given_name
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#r').append(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: Now it's calling the `ajax` when I type on input field which I don't want. I want to call this `ajax` when user actually type something on input field and hover out the mouse from this input field.